# How to send and receive a text file from C to Java using tcp/ip protocol?

Tags: c, sockets, system, system-calls, tcp

I am able to send  a text file to java, but when i am receiving the file i am getting the text in hexadecimal format. How to receive the a file without data loss and other malfunctions. I am giving the receiving code for further references.

```
  int receive_text(int socket)
  { 
      int buffersize=8192,recv_size=0,read_size = 1, write_size,size; 
      char pBuf[80],a[50],MAXDATASIZE; 
      int errnom,i;
      FILE *text; 
      size_t rec;
      text = fopen("/home/sosdt009/Desktop/receivednew.txt", "a");  
      if (text == NULL) 
      {     
         printf("Error has occurred, text file could not be opened \n");
         return -1;
      }

      //Loop while we have not received the entire file yet

      while(read_size > 0)
      {

            ioctl(socket, FIONREAD, &buffersize);
            printf("The Buffersize is    :%d\n",buffersize);
            gets(a);
            printf("The size of socket is:%d\n",socket);
            gets(a);

         //We check to see if there is data to be read from the socket 

        if (buffersize > 0)
        {
            printf("Buffersize value is  :%d\n", buffersize);
            gets(a);
            if (!pBuf)
            {
                printf(errnom, "Memory Error Cannot Allocate!\n");
                gets(a);
                exit(-1);
            }

            read_size = recv(socket, sizeof(pBuf),MAXDATASIZE,0);
            printf("Read size value is :%d \n",read_size);
            gets(a);
            printf("Buffersize value is:%d \n",pBuf);
            gets(a);
            if (read_size < 0)
            {
                printf("%d\n",strerror(errno));
                printf("Data not written to the file:\n");
                gets(a);
            }
             /Write the currently read data into our text file

             write_size = fwrite(pBuf,1,sizeof(pBuf),text); 
             printf("Write size value is   :%d \n",write_size);
             gets(a);
             printf("Buffer size value is  :%d \n",buffersize);
             gets(a);

             //Increment the total number of bytes read
            recv_size += read_size;
            printf("Received size value is:%d \n",recv_size);
            gets(a);
            printf("Read size value is    :%d \n",read_size);       
            gets(a);    
        }
     }
    free:
    fclose(text);
    close(socket);  
    printf("Text Successfully Received:\n");
    gets(a);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the sender function in c

```
 int send_text(int socket)
 { 
     FILE *text;
     char a[50];
     int size, read_size, stat, packet_index;
     char send_buffer[8008], read_buffer[8008];
     int wrt=0,sock_fd,tsize=0;
     packet_index = 1;
     int i=0; 
     text = fopen("/home/sosdt009/Desktop/character3.txt", "r"); 
     if (text == NULL)
     {
         printf("Error Opening text File:");
         exit(-1);
     }  
     printf("Getting text Size:\n");
     gets(a);
     fseek(text, 0, SEEK_END);
     size = ftell(text);
     fseek(text, 0, SEEK_SET);
     printf("Total text size: %d \n", size);    
     gets(a);

     //Send text Size

     printf("Sending text Size:\n",size);
     gets(a);
     send(socket, (void *)&size, sizeof(size), 0);

     while(stat < 0)
     printf("Socket data:%s \n", read_buffer); 
     gets(a);   
     while(size>tsize) 
     {

         //Read from the file into our send buffer
         read_size = fread(send_buffer,1,sizeof(send_buffer),text);
         printf("The size of send buffer:%c \n", sizeof(send_buffer));
         gets(a);
         printf("The read size value is :%d \n", read_size);
         gets(a);

    //Send data through our socket 

    do
    {           
        stat = send(socket, send_buffer, read_size, 0);
        printf("The send size value is: %d \n", size);
        gets(a);
        printf("The read size value is: %d \n", read_size);
        gets(a);

    } while (stat < 0); 
    printf("Packet %d, sent %d bytes.\n", packet_index, read_size);
    gets(a);

    //packet_index++;
    //Zero out our send buffer

    tsize = tsize+read_size;
    printf("The tsize value is:%d \n",tsize);
    gets(a);
        memset(send_buffer,0, sizeof(send_buffer));

    if(read_size<=NULL)
    {
        printf("The connection is transferred to received text: \n");
        gets(a);
    }
    }
    fclose(text);
    printf("Text successfully send:\n");
     gets(a);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: What does "received in hexadecimal format" mean?

Comment: (Also, I know someone is going to complain about `gets(a)`, so I'll pre-emptively point out that it's clearly not production code)

Comment: Actually very few characters are received  and other null characters are shown, that is the what i have meant as hexadecimal characters.

Comment: `if (!pBuf)` cannot be true, because `pBuf` is an array.

Comment: and you should write the number of the received bytes to the file, not the size of the buffer. You cannot write 50 bytes if you received only 20 bytes.

Comment: @mch. can you specify this in coding for better understanding

Comment: `write_size = fwrite(pBuf,1,sizeof(pBuf),text);` ==> `write_size = fwrite(pBuf,1,read_size,text);`

Comment: @mch: I have tried with what you have said, but still the output is not displayed in the text file.

Comment: you should open the file with `"wb"`(binary mode), if you want to use `fwrite`. If you only receive text, you can use `fprintf`. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html

Comment: @mch: I have tried with "wb" mode as you told, but still i am facing the same error.

Comment: 'printf("Socket data:%s \n", read_buffer);' tries to printf an uninitialized buffer as a a null-terminated string, but since it only does this if the uninitialized 'stat' is lss than 0, I guess one UB covers up the other?

Comment: When you used your debugger to check the contents, and data length, of what is sent and received, and used wireshark to check what is actually sent/received, was the problem at the sender or receiver?

Comment: @ Martin james: Can you kindly put your idea in a piece of code, so that i can check it out..

Comment: No.  SO contributors cannot effectively do debugging/testing on a distributed system.  Use your debugger and wireshark to narrow down the problem area.  ATM, you don't even know if the sender, receiver or both is causing the bug/s.  Do some work.